# AngularJS directive with template having ng-repeat and ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a `directive` with template having `ng-repeat` and `ng-bind-html` as below

```
app.directive('customField', function ($compile) {

var getTemplate = function (customType) {
 return  '<span  ng-repeat ="option in  custom.options" ng-bind-html="option"></span>';
}

var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html(getTemplate(scope.custom.type)).show();
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
}

return {
    restrict: "E",
    rep1ace: true,
    link: linker,
    scope: {
        custom: '='
    }
};
});
```

but this gives error:
`Error: [$sce:unsafe] Attempting to use an unsafe value in a safe context`.

In normal scenario I use `$sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);` to resolve this type of issue , but in directive with `ng-repeat` how to solve this?

Comment: bind $sce.trustAsHtml() as a scope function and call it ?

Comment: Or use `ngSanitize` !

Comment: Whose suggestion ? Bixi's or mine ? :)

Comment: Both solution are fine , but I have used Bixi's since I don't want to add one more js 'angular-sanitize.js'. :D

Comment: @DurGeshkuMarRAO: Yes, it's always preferable to avoid adding one more tiny cachable script in favor of making your app less secure :P